# Python3 - Check Hyper-V VM replication status

Tags: python-3.x, hyper-v

I am trying to get the replication status of a Hyper-V vm using python.
The snippet that I am trying to get working is:

```
import wmi
for svrName in serverList:
        c = wmi.WMI ( 
        computer=svrName,
        user=r"domain\username,
        password=r"MyPassword"
        )
        for vm in c.Msvm_ReplicationService():   
            print (vm.InstanceID)
```

The error I am getting is:

pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'SWbemServicesEx', 'Not found ', None, 0, -2147217406), None)

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Regards,

Leslie